# does J2ME support inheritance of Form an List classes

Tags: java, java-me

i am creating a Music Player in J2ME. I am trying to extend the Form and List class but the IDE show some error. So , i just want to confirm whether it is possible to extend theses classes in J2Me.

Comment: Yeah it should support. What error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Form and List J2ME classes are not final, so these classes can be extended.